# Word/Phrase for a person who receives a complaint from someone

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns, paraphrasing

I'm creating a policy and procedure in one of my subjects and am wondering is there another way of saying "a person that received a complaint". I know there's way for a person being complained about but not the receiver of the complaint.

Example sentence:

> The person who received a complaint will report the incident to the General Manager

I'm looking for a replacement for *the person who received a complaint*.

Answer (score 1):

A useful general term that includes but is not specific to complaints is **recipient**.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recipient)
> recipient:
> a person or organization that receives something, such as money, a prize, etc
>
> a recipient of something
> *They are the country's biggest recipient of government funds.*
> *As a grant recipient, you are required to write an annual report.*
> *The recipient organization is responsible for monitoring expenditure.*

One of many examples of the usage specific to complaints is in:

> [University of Bath](https://www.bath.ac.uk/guides/student-complaints-policy-and-procedure/)
>
> *Recipients of informal student complaints are responsible for addressing them promptly and fairly. The recipient will normally let the student know (or arrange for a colleague to do so) within five working days of receiving the initial complaint what steps (if any) will be taken to address the complaint and the expected timescale, and advise to whom they should submit a formal complaint if they are dissatisfied with this outcome.*

Comment: Indeed. Depending on the complaint procedure, "(complaint) handler", "customer service representative" (CSR), "agent", "rep", "contact", or anything like that may or may not be relevant. Ideally a business should specify who can or cannot receive a complaint, as not everybody will be empowered to.